# Link and image centered

Tags: html, css, image, centering

Can someone help me to bring the image vertically centered beside the text (both should be vertically centered? I have some troubles with this, because the link with the image is not on the same height as the text in the other rows.

Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/k7CVE/

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean the image in column `result`? Link + image are centered, at least in Chrome. Or do you want the image below the link?

Comment: @mliebelt: The image is not vertically centered in chrome , there is more space above the image.

Comment: Sorry, mixed vertical / hoizontal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try **'text-bottom'** instead of 'middle' for vertical-align property like in your case it would be

```
img.load-icon {
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0px solid black;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
}
```